# Flutter RefreshIndicator on listview inside column

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Hei, i have flutter app where all of page covered by listview in main.dart.
on other page i have column also with listview inside, when i use RefreshIndicator on that list its not work, except the list physic set to AlwaysScrollablePhysc, but if i set physc to AlwaysScrollablePhysc the list not Scrollable,
anybody can help?

```
RefreshIndicator(
  onRefresh: () {},
  child: ListView.builder(
    physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    controller: _scrollController,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: list == null ? 0 : list.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
```

Comment: From your description it is not clear what the problem is. Maybe you could add some more code that fully demonstrates the behavior.

Comment: the problem is **Listview** inside Listview not working with 
 **AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics** but i need **AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics** for **RefreshIndicator** work,

main.dart body is using **Listview** to cover all page so its not overflowed. im using bottom navbar. then my otherpage.dart using using **Listview** inside a column.